# TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float32') and format specifier ('%5.2f , %5.2f , %5.2f')

Tags: python, file, floating-point, formatting

I am stuck with a format issue during reading/storing files. Any comment/remark is welcome how to solve this.

I am defining some arrays

```
pos_pb_now = np.array(pos_pb_now, dtype='f')   # 6x3
pos_pw_now = np.array(pos_pw_now, dtype='f')  #6x3
pos_ball_now = np.array(pos_ball_now, dtype='f')  # 1x3
```

save the data later in a file

```
np.savetxt(f_store_handler, pos_pb_now, fmt='%5.2f', delimiter=' , ')
np.savetxt(f_store_handler, pos_pw_now, fmt='%5.2f', delimiter=' , ')
np.savetxt(f_store_handler, pos_ball_now, fmt='%5.2f', delimiter=' , ')
```

recover the data later for further use; only in 1 array of size (n*13) x 3 and this line below is initializing it.

```
array_coord_sequence = np.loadtxt(filename_coord_retrieve, delimiter=',', skiprows=0, dtype='f')
```

Then I modify the array_coord_sequence and want to store it again in one time

```
np.savetxt(f_store_handler_local, array_coord_sequence, fmt='%5.2f', delimiter=' , ')
```

but errors comes up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
store coord into file new/overwriting pos_uwr_player.csv
  File "/home/family/glade/game_uwr/game_uwr.py", line 1844, in store_file_coord
    np.savetxt(f_store_handler_local, array_coord_sequence, fmt='%5.2f', delimiter=' , ')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1219, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float32') and format specifier ('%5.2f , %5.2f , %5.2f')
```

Update 1: example of a code how array_coord_sequence is modified (lfd_seq is an integer)

```
    for k in range(6):
        array_coord_sequence[k + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13, 0] = pos_pb_now[k, 0]
        array_coord_sequence[k + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13, 1] = pos_pb_now[k, 1]
        array_coord_sequence[k + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13, 2] = pos_pb_now[k, 2]
        array_coord_sequence[k + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13 + 6, 0] = pos_pw_now[k, 0]
        array_coord_sequence[k + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13 + 6, 1] = pos_pw_now[k, 1]
        array_coord_sequence[k + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13 + 6, 2] = pos_pw_now[k, 2]

    array_coord_sequence[12 + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13, 0] = pos_ball_now[0, 0]
    array_coord_sequence[12 + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13, 1] = pos_ball_now[0, 1]
    array_coord_sequence[12 + (lfd_seq - 1) * 13, 2] = pos_ball_now[0, 2]
```

Comment: How did you modify `array_coord_sequence`. What is its type and shape?

Comment: See update 1. type "f". shape (n*13) lines and 3 columns.

Comment: cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: You can shorten your code with: `array_coord_sequence[n:n+6] = pos_pb_now`

Comment: I opened wrongly the file with             f_store_handler_local = open(filename_coord_store, 'w'). It must be             f_store_handler_local = open(filename_coord_store, 'wb'). topic closed. Thanks for the code shortening tip.